# I wrote a delete method for a node in Linked List at specific index (Java) but it makes no changes to the list?

Tags: java, linked-list

The code makes no changes to the output and just reprints the original linked list and I don't know whether the problem is with my delete method or with the access specifiers I used for my Stack.

1. List item

Public static class Stack
{

```
     Node first; *// newest node added*
    private int size;
     class Node
    {  
           String item;
           Node next; 

    }
    public Node delete(int index,Stack list)
    {  

        if (list.first== null) {
            return null;
        } else if (index == 0) 
        {
            return list.first.next;
        }
        else
        {
            Node n = list.first;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) 
            {
                n = n.next;
                if(i==index)
                n.next = n.next.next;//skips over the existing element

            }
            return list.first;
        }
        }
```

}

//client test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        StdOut.print("Type the linked list:");
        Stack list = new Stack();
        int index;
        String in=StdIn.readLine();
        for(int i=0;i<=in.length();i++)
        {
         list.push(in);
        }
        StdOut.print("Type the index to be deleted:");
        index=StdIn.readInt();
        StdOut.println("Before deleting element at "+ index);
        StdOut.println(in);



        StdOut.println("After deleting element at "+ index);
        StdOut.print(list.delete(index,list).item);


}
```

}

Comment: It's better to fix the code formatting so others can easily understand it.

Comment: in this loop `for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)` value for `i` cannot be greater than `index - 2` so this condition `if(i==index)` is always `false`

Answer (score 0):

In your delete() function, you are returning `list.first` - which is pointing to the head node of the list, and not the `Node first* //newest node added*`, correct? I think you should just be returning from the function when the delete task is complete instead of returning `null` or a `node`.

Also, as you iterate through the list in the final else statement, you should move the `n = n.next;` line below the index check.

Your delete() function would look something like this:

```
public Node delete(int index,Stack list)
{  

    if (list.first== null) 
    {
        return;
    } else if (index == 0) 
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node n = list.first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) 
        {
            //If the next Node of the current node is +1 the current index
            if(i+1==index)
            {
                n.next = n.next.next;//skips over the existing element
                return;
            }

            n = n.next;

        }
        return;
    }
 }
```

And :

```
list.delete(index,list).item; //call the delete function
StdOut.println("After deleting element at "+ index);
list.print(); //Print the list using its print function (assuming you have one)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this still always `false`: `if (i+1 == index)`. if `index` is `4` than `i` cannot be greater than 2

Comment: Whoops! Updated to be just 'index' and not 'index-1' in the for loop

Comment: I still get the same linked list without anything being deleted.

Comment: How are you inserting Nodes and printing the list?

Comment: I am using the following push and pop methods to insert nodes:

Comment: public void push(String in)
       {  // Adds item to top 
          Node previous = first;
          first = new Node();
          first.item = in;
          first.next = previous;
          size++;
       }
       
       
       public String pop()
       {  // Removes item from top 
          String item = first.item;
          first = first.next;
          size--;
          return item;
       }

Comment: and the following code for printing:StdOut.print(list.pop().trim());